Math Bingo: Can Y|X be normally distributed but Y is not normal?
This is a question we had in our frosh math bingo. We were asked to come up with a instance in which random variables Y|X be normally distributed but Y is not normal.
This is my attempt:
Law of total probability for random variables:
$$ f_Y(y) = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f_{Y|X}(y|x) f_X(x) dx $$

$f_Y(y)$ is the unconditional density of Y
$f_{Y|X}(y|x)$ is the conditional density of Y given X
$f_X(x)$ is the density of X.

After giving it some thought, I think there are an infinite number of cases that satisfy this question. For example:
$$ Y|X \sim N(\mu_X, \sigma^2) $$
$$ X \sim \text{Exponential}(\lambda) $$
The conditional density of Y given X is:
$$ f_{Y|X}(y|x) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi\sigma^2}} \exp\left(-\frac{(y-x)^2}{2\sigma^2}\right) $$
The density of X is:
$$ f_X(x) = \lambda e^{-\lambda x} \text{ for } x \geq 0 $$
Using the law of total probability, we can calculate the unconditional density of Y:
$$ f_Y(y) = \int_0^{\infty} \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi\sigma^2}} \exp\left(-\frac{(y-x)^2}{2\sigma^2}\right) \lambda e^{-\lambda x} dx $$
As such, it seems to me that the above expression is not a Normal Distribution. Im sure we could probably take the characteristic equation of the above equation and show that it does not equal the characteristic equation of a normal distribution ... but I think that would be overkill and not necessary.
Did I get this question correct?

Hint: Combine exponents and complete the square to get something easier to work with

So there are easier counter-examples if you don't shy away from discrete random variables. For example, let $X$ be Bernoulli and sample $Y \sim \mathcal{N}(kX, 1)$. To show that $Y$ is not normal, use the fact that it is bimodal (for $k$ large enough...).
